# If $f = ax - by + 0c$, with non-negative $x$, $y$, $c$, and $x+y+c=n$, all integers, then how many distinct values does $f$ take?

Tags: computational-mathematics

> Given a function $f = ax - by + 0c$, with constraints $y\geq 0$, $x\geq 0$, $c\geq 0$, and $x+y+c=n$, where all are integers. I am interested to find the count of all unique values of $f$.

I know that total number of different arrangements of $a$, $b$, $c$ are
 $(n+1)(n+2)/2$. But how do I know how many these arrangements have same value of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ have a common factor then so does every $f$.   So divide $a$ and $b$ by the common factor.  From now on, $a$ and $b$ are coprime.
$(x,y)$ lies within a triangle.
Note $f=ax-by+0c=a(x-b)-b(y-a)+0c$ so only count $(x,y)$ if $(x-b,y-a)$ lies outside the triangle, otherwise the same $f$ is counted twice.

Suppose $n=5$, $a=2$ and $b=3$.  The triangle has vertices $(0,0), (0,5)$ and $(5,0)$.  The bottom three rows should all be counted because $x-3\lt0$ which is outside the triangle.  For the other rows, only the first two columns should be counted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example that triangle part?

Comment: Still didn't understand what you are saying.

Comment: The triangle bounded by $x\ge0,y\ge0, x+y\le n$ has vertices at $(0,0),(0,n)$ and $(n,0)$.

Comment: For your cited example, I have 21 combinations and of which 2 will give 0 as the value of f, so the answer becomes 20. Can you show this using your answer?

Comment: The bottom three rows contain 6+5+4 points = 15.  The other three rows have 3+2+1 points, but only count the first two of each, which is 2+2+1=5. Total = 15+5 = 20.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I am not able to get what you are saying.

Comment: Can you explain for n=70, a=4 and b=8.

Comment: Now, I understood, thanks a lot.